# Ask if user really want to close bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, hide, confirm

I have a bootstrap modal. When it is closed some instructions are executed. But now I want to ask if user really want to close it (with a confirm window) What can i do?

Here is my code at the moment.

```
$('#modal').on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
    //Instructions to execute when the modal is closed
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('#modal').on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
   if(confirm("Are you sure, you want to close?")) return true;
   else return false;
});
```

Or, just like this:

```
$('#modal').on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
   if(!confirm("Are you sure, you want to close?")) return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I need. Thanks. It is easier than I thougt :)

Comment: Glad, I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modal').on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
  //Instructions to execute when the modal is closed
 if(!confirm("Are you sure, you want to close?")) return false;
});
```